# How can can I do case insensitive search in postresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have such postresql table:

```
id  user    year        id_card_no

1   john    1995        AZE546546       
2   ali     2002        464645AZE               
3   hayat   2007        4454AZE45455            
4   jack    2008        455454554
```

I want to get all values which have `AZE` word inside column (**id_card_no**) field. I used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  id_card_no LIKE '%AZE%'
```

But I got first field which `id` is equal to `1`. How can I get all columns which have `AZE` word inside `id_card_no`?

Comment: With the given sample data and query you should get the other rows as well. Are you sure you are showing us the correct example? (And you probably mean: *How can I get all **rows** which have..*, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing a case insensitive LIKE you have two options:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE  id_card_no ILIKE '%AZE%'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE lower(id_card_no) LIKE lower('%AZE%')
```

Comment: Great answer. But can I use 2 query together like that?:
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE  id_card_no ILIKE '%AZE%' or ILIKE '%AZA%'

Comment: Sure. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: as LIKE and ILIKE are actually operators in PostgreSQL, you also can use `id_card_no ilike ANY ( ARRAY['%AZE%','%AZA%'] )`

Answer (score 1):

This kind of select do not scale as they are doomed to sequential scans on pre-9.1 PostgreSQL.

If your table is going to be big, then it is better, that you read about the trigram indexes and possibilities of their use in 9.1 for speeding up substring searches.

If you are not on PostgreSQL 9.1, you should consider creating a GIN/GIST index on arrays of substrings and then using array access operators to make index scans possible.